# hide password from reading from .o file or .hex file

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino, password-protection

I'm writing a project on arduino and I'm storing a password in a const char array. This password is written in the code and I would like to hide the password from malicious readers who have access to the .o files and .hex files.

Does anyone happen to know how to hide it?

I allready tryed by storing it in a const byte array instead of a const char array, but it doesn't seems to solve my problem...

Comment: an array's almost always going to be stored as consecutive bytes, so the pw chars are going to be very near/consecutive regardless of what you do. You should spread them around individual chars with other vars defined in between, then assemble the pw string in code, with added things like xor obfuscation and whatnot. Not bulletproof, but will stop your basic script kiddie.

Comment: But ultimately, the password is in the file.  Someone who's determined to find it will eventually manage to find it.

Comment: @MarcB a few minutes in a debugger will easily reveal the assembled password.

Comment: @chris: hence saying it'll only stop basic script kiddies who wouldn't know a debugger if they shoved it up their nose

Comment: @MarcB I suppose, if that's the definition of script kiddie. It wouldn't take too much skill though.

Comment: @chris: script kiddie = some dweeb who can only run pre-made attack scripts and couldn't code their way out of a paper bag.

Comment: Do you need to store the actual password? Normally this would be the job of something like a hash+salt. I realize this is an embedded platform, but it's a possibility.

Comment: In fact, I need to decrypt some data received trough internet. I cant see how hashing the password can help me since I have to recover the password if I need to decrypt the data... But thanks anyway!

Comment: @Marc B: hmm I might want to update my user profile then :)

Comment: Assume this is a double entry with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025494/obfuscating-c-c-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the password in [EEPROM](http://arduino.cc/it/Reference/EEPROM), which you can write to with avrdude or inside your code. In the latter case you will need to provide the password to your device at some point after flashing.

The password will still be accessible to anyone with physical access to the device, but not people who only have access to `.o` and `.hex` files.

I am not sure if the Arduino bootloader allows you to read and write EEPROM through avrdude, but if not, you could write an initial Arduino sketch that writes the password to EEPROM, then later overwrite it with your actual sketch that only reads it.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part is that no matter what, since you need to use the password, (and I'm assuming you can't enter a key every time you boot) your code is going to contain both the lock, and the key to opening it. The real question is how good does this have to be?

If it doesn't have to be real good, you could xor the password by some value, and use that as the password in the source. You then xor it by the same value when you need to use it, and ta-da...

If you want something less trivial (and the arduino fits it), you could sign the password with your private key, and store your public key in the source. The algorithm to unsign the password is considerably more complex than a simple xor (thus harder to spot.)

*No matter what, any self-contained system that needs to use plaintext passwords is compromisable.*

Comment: thanks, but I think that a system using public and private key can be much SRAM expensive...

Answer (score 1):

Just hash the password and store the hash. Than you hash the user input password to try and match them.

Now, if you need to store a password to another service and you can't help but use the plain password with their API, then you have few possible choices.

Comment: thanks, the problem has been solved but I appreciate your interest